# How to add two array of objects as one array of object react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arrayobject

Hello Everyone I am new to javascript and ReactJs. Can someone guide me How can I combine two or more array of objects as one array of object in react or javascript.

here is e.g:

```
Object1: [
    {
      cell: 2225,
      name: "abc",
      add: "Hell",
      city: "York",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      cell: 1425,
      name: "Bol",
      add: "Lem",
      city: "York",
      id: 2
    }
    .
    .
  ]
  Object2: [
    {
      cell: 3334,
      name: "Zak",
      add: "NewY",
      city: "NewY",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      cell: 444,
      name: "Sachin",
      add: "Mum",
      city: "Lon",
      id: 2
    }
    .
    .
  ]
```

result I am expecting:

```
Object3: [
    {
      cell: 2225,
      name: "abc",
      add: "Hell",
      city: "York",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      cell: 1425,
      name: "Bol",
      add: "Lem",
      city: "York",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      cell: 3334,
      name: "Zak",
      add: "NewY",
      city: "NewY",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      cell: 444,
      name: "Sachin",
      add: "Mum",
      city: "Lon",
      id: 2
    }
  ]
```

I know its simple but its new for me,I checked some example on stackoverflow and other site but didn't understand.Can someone give me the simpe example how can i achieve this.In my case i dont want to avoid duplicate object it should be add as it is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please share your attempt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: no that is different what i am expecting.

Comment: **two or more array of objects** - How do you get to know the number of objects that needs to be merged i.e. `Object1, Object2, ... ObjectN`?

Comment: in that case its avoiding duplicate but in my case i dont want to avoid

Comment: that example is combining the two array.But in my case i want to combine two array of object.

Comment: @Zaif - You can combine the array of objects in the same way. Additionally, adding to my previous question, how do you know how many arrays are there in total?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal in my case there are 3 arrays and in that it can be any number of object will be there.

Comment: So, you want to merge 3 arrays into 1 array and there can be duplicate objects in the resultant array. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes it can be duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you wanted.

```
    let Arr = {
      Object1: [
        {
          cell: 2225,
          name: "abc",
          add: "Hell",
          city: "York",
          id: 1
        },
        {
          cell: 1425,
          name: "Bol",
          add: "Lem",
          city: "York",
          id: 2
        }
      ],
      Object2: [
        {
          cell: 3334,
          name: "Zak",
          add: "NewY",
          city: "NewY",
          id: 1
        },
        {
          cell: 444,
          name: "Sachin",
          add: "Mum",
          city: "Lon",
          id: 2
        }
      ]
    };
    let Object3 = [];

    Object3.push(...Arr.Object1, ...Arr.Object2);
    console.log(Object3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let Object1 = [
  {
    cell: 2225,
    name: "abc",
    add: "Hell",
    city: "York",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    cell: 1425,
    name: "Bol",
    add: "Lem",
    city: "York",
    id: 2
  }
];

let Object2 = [
  {
    cell: 3334,
    name: "Zak",
    add: "NewY",
    city: "NewY",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    cell: 444,
    name: "Sachin",
    add: "Mum",
    city: "Lon",
    id: 2
  }
];
      
let Object3 = [...Object1, ...Object2];

console.log(Object3);
```